# angular2: asp.net core service throws 'No access control allow origin' when Windows Authentication is on

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular

I have any `angular2` app  accessing `asp.net core webapi` service. It is working if webapi iis configuration is (Properties\launchSettings.json):

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12246/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
```

However, it throws the error once `WindowsAuthentication` is `true` and AnonymousAuthentication is `false`. The error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:12246/api//values/getSettings. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Any idea please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [401 response for CORS request in IIS with Windows Auth enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723088/401-response-for-cors-request-in-iis-with-windows-auth-enabled)

Comment: this.http.get(url, {withCredentials :true}) raises another error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:12246/api//values/getSettings. Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @beewest please refer this for ASP.NET core web api - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423621/angular-2-aspnetcore-webapi-cors-issue-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http/39423703#39423703

Comment: @sanket: sorry but not work

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to make a cross-origin request. This is permitted under the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) specification, but requires configuration.

There are three steps to fixing this problem.

1. Configure both web servers to use Windows Authentication (and disable anonymous authentication). That is, both the server hosting your Angular 2 app *and* the server hosting your ASP.NET Core WebAPI app must be configured.
2. Enable CORS your ASP.NET Core WebAPI app:

   in your Startup.cs file:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseCors(builder =>
           builder
           .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")  //<-- OP's origin
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowCredentials()
           );
       }

       app.UseMvc();
   }
   ```
3. Have Angular 2 send your credentials along with its CORS request:

   ```
   import {Injectable}         from '@angular/core'
   import {Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
   import {Observable}         from 'rxjs/Observable';

   import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

   @Injectable()
   export class SomeAngularServiceThatCallsYourAPI{

       constructor(private http: Http) { }

       getApiData(): Promise<MyDataResult[]> {

           var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:12246/api//values/getSettings';
           return this.http.get(apiUrl,{
               withCredentials: true
           })
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => this.extractData(response) as MyDataResult[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
       }

   }
   ```

For further details, see my [blog post](https://matthew-evans-dpjx.squarespace.com/blog/2016/12/19/making-cross-origin-cors-requests-to-aspnet-core-webapi-from-angular-2-under-windows-authentication).